# Is 0* decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability

I found a statement (without explanation) that a language $A = 0^*$ is decidable. How is that possible? I mean, how would we build a Turing machine that would accept (or reject) a possibly infinite string of 0's? I also thought that maybe we could create an enumerator that would create all words from $0^*$ with increasing length, but I am not sure if we can.

So is $0^*$ a decidable language? And if so, why?

Comment: Well 0* is regular, so we can create a DFA for it. Since $A_{DFA}$ is decidable, 0* is decidable.

Comment: $0^* \neq 0^\omega$. Only the latter contains infinite strings.

Comment: And that is the trap I fell into - mistaking an infinite number of words with words of infinite length ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$0^*$ is the set of finite strings consisting only of $0$. There are no possibly infinite strings in $0^*$. It is trivially regular because the regex $0^*$ accepts exactly $A$ by definition. All regular problems are computable so we can definitely create a Turing machine for it (look up [NFA's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) and [DFA's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) for more info on the connection of Turing machines to regular languages).

This is just a confusion in what is meant by Kleene closure. If you look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) you can see that it is the union of all strings of length 1, 2, 3, ... and so on for all natural numbers. Infinity is not a natural number so there are no strings of infinite length in $A$.

Comment: So knowing I accept only 0* I could "go through" the whole input and just assure no other symbol than 0 appears, and when I reach blank symbol (meaning empy piece of the tape is reached) I accept?

Comment: Yes. You misunderstood what $0^*$ means. It does not mean "infinite string of $0$'s". It means "the set of all finite strings of $0$'s". This set does not contain any infinite strings.

Comment: @RickyDemer Please just edit the post!

Answer (score 10):

The kleene star of a language $L$ is defined as 
\begin{align}
  L^\star = \{ w \mid  w = \epsilon \text{ or } w = w_1\circ w_2 \circ \ldots \circ w_k, \text{ where } w_i \in L \text{ and } k \in \mathbb{N} \}.
\end{align}
Thus there is no such thing as an infinite string of $0$'s in the language $0^\star$, only strings of zeros of arbitrary length.

We can easily construct an DFA that accepts the language $A$: it has only one state $s$, which is both start and end state, and one transition $(s, 0) \mapsto s$. Therefore the language $A$ is regular and also decidable.